# Android Studio: multiple layouts, specifically landscape tablet

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, tablet, landscape-portrait

I am creating an application for a school project within Android Studio. I am required to make the application run on both phones and tablets in both landscape and portrait modes. I have created 3 different layouts for my homepage by opening the Design View and selecting Create XXXX Variation from the Orientation For Preview Section. So now I have a variation for portrait phone, landscape phone, and tablet but I still need one for landscape tablet. I noticed there is a Create Other Variation but I am not exactly sure how I would go about setting that to landscape tablet. Any advice is appreciated

For reference, here is what my layout folder looks like with my different variations.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click **Create Other..** Select **Orientation** from Available Qualifiers box. Click **>>** button. In Screen Orientation select **Landscape**. In directory name paste this : **layout-sw600dp-land**

A new folder will be created with the same name having activity_main.xml in sw600dp(tablet 7" size) in landscape mode. Configure as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

For a tablet you might use resource directory `large`, `xlarge` and `large-land`, `xlarge-land`.